# CakePHP 2.x RSS Feed Route

Tags: cakephp, rss, feed, routes

For my CakePHP Blog I created an RSS Feed as described in the [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/rss.html)
.

Now I can't find or access the feed and I think it might have sth to do with my custom route. I access my Post Index with this route:

```
Router::connect('/:city/blog', array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 
    'action' => 'index'
    ), 
    array(
      'city' => '[a-z]+'
      )
);
```

How would I write a Route for this Feed Url?: *domain.com/washington/blog/index.rss*

(By the way: I followed the docs in detail, so I did add: `Router::parseExtensions('rss');` to routes.php)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In routes.php Where did you placed the Router::parseExtensions('rss'); code ?? I did it at the beginning and worked for me.

[image]

Let me know more about it

Comment: Jepp, placed it at the beginning too. That is weird … did you add anything else?

Comment: I made some fixes on the route rule. Try this Router::connect('/:city/blog/index', array('controller' => 'posts', 
                                     'action' => 'index', 
                                     'url' => array('ext' => 'rss')
                                ),array(
      'city' => '[a-z]+'
      ) );